# General solution of $x^2 u_{xx} - 2xy u_{xy} + y^2 u_{yy} = e^x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable, parabolic-pde, fundamental-solution

I am trying to find the general solution of $x^{2} u_{xx} -2xy u_{xy} + y^{2} u_{yy} = e^{x}$. The equation is parabolic as the only root of the characteristic equation is $\lambda = \frac{y}{x}$. Changing variables to $\xi (x,y) = xy, \eta (x, y) = y$, one gets that the canonical form of the aforementioned PDE is

$
v_{\eta \eta} - \frac{2 \xi}{\eta ^2} v_{\xi} - \frac{1}{\eta ^2} e^{\frac{\xi}{\eta}} = 0.
$

I know it's possible to find an explicit expression for the general solution, but I don't know how to do it. I have tried to approach the problem by finding first the general solution of the homogeneous case (taking the $e^{\frac{\xi}{\eta}}$ out of the equation), but I still don't know what to do.

:(

Comment: Could you please provide a quick sketch of the process?

Comment: I understand the idea, but I don't know how to turn the canonical form into an PDE of order 1.

Comment: But $(x \partial_{x} - y \partial_{y})$ is an operator with non-constant coefficients, so expanding the square does not lead to the original equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try to separate variables with $u(x,y)=f_1(x)+f_2(y)$

This leads to
$$x^{2} \left(\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}\mathit{f_1}\! \left(x\right)\right)+y^{2} \left(\frac{d^{2}}{d y^{2}}\mathit{f_2}\! \left(y\right)\right)={\mathrm e}^{x}$$

This equation can be solved by the identities:
$$\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}f_{1}\! \left(x\right)=\frac{k}{x^{2}}+\frac{{\mathrm e}^{x}}{x^{2}}$$

$$\frac{d^{2}}{d y^{2}}f_{2}\! \left(y\right)=-\frac{k}{y^{2}}$$

Verify:
$$x^{2}\cdot \left(\frac{k}{x^{2}}+\frac{{\mathrm e}^{x}}{x^{2}}\right)+y^{2}\cdot \left(-\frac{k}{y^{2}}\right)=e^{x}$$

Now we can solve both separated ODEs:

$$\mathit{f_1}(x)= \mathrm{Ei}\! \left(x\right)\cdot \left(x-1\right)-{\mathrm e}^{x}-k\cdot \ln\! \left(x\right)+c_{1}\cdot x+c_{2}$$

$$f_{2}(y)= k\cdot\ln\left(y\right)+C_{1} y+C_{2}$$

**HINT:** $Ei(z)$ is the exponential integral.

Finally we get

$$u(x,y)=\mathrm{Ei}\! \left(x\right)\cdot \left(x-1\right)-{\mathrm e}^{x}+c_{1}\cdot x+c_{2}+k\cdot \ln\! \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+C_{1}\cdot y+C_{2}$$

$[k, c_1, c_2, C_1, C_2] \in \mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary constants.

**PS** I'm not pretty sure if this is the **most** general solution.